# Castle Windsor ResolveAll that throws when any of registered services cannot be resolved

Tags: castle-windsor, throw, resolve

It seems that current behaviour of Castle Windsor (2.0) method

```
container.ResolveAll(Type type)
```

is to ignore all services that cannot be resolved due to missing dependencies. What is recommened way to resolve all services + throwing exception when any of services cannot be resolved?

Comment: This is expected behavior, and that's what you'd want most of the time, so this is not going to change.

Comment: @Krzysztof I know but I also wanted this some times. Making it optional wouldn't hurt...

Comment: I see you found yourself quite a nice workaround.
And if you want this, because you want to get 'notified' when you mis-wired your container, check that in unit tests - http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/06/27/testing-castle-windsor-mappings-part-deux.aspx

Comment: what would be a reasonable scenario when you'd really want that? I can't think of any

Comment: I was experimentally porting an application from some other DI container to castle windsor, and resolveall did not return all services (due to miswired container). Once I found out how ResolveAll actually works, I had no problem fixing it...but I still don't understand why is it more appropriate for ResolveAll to ignore misconfigured services than to throw exception? In what scenario do you resolve all prior to registering all dependancies?

Comment: This is a super frustrating behavior, and has wasted countless hours of my team's life. Has the hack worked out for you well? Considering it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built-in way to do that and I've been thinking about implementing an option to throw instead of ignoring invalid components. However, this has some consequences that need to be thought through.

In the meantime, [here's a hack](http://mausch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/WindsorInitConfig/WindsorInitConfig/ResolveAllThrowing.cs). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. I hoped it would be integrated in windsor, so thanks for clearing that up.